# How can I stop event bubbling when clicking on item, but I'm using it to select the item

Tags: javascript, color-scheme

I'm using JavaScript ES5.

I'm making a colour scheme selection, like WordPress.

All works good, however, when I click on the radio button or the colors, it doesn't change. If I click on the li e.g padding, it changes.

The event.target gets the targeted element, which makes sense. However, how can I get only its parent? Which is the div?

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/QQLRJx?editors=1010

Here's the JS:

```
var schemeColorList = document.querySelector('.scheme-color__list');
    var schemeColorOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.scheme-color__option');
    var schemeColorRadio = document.querySelectorAll('.scheme-color__option input');

    var schemeColorPalette = document.querySelectorAll('.scheme-color__palette');
    var schemeColorPaletteBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.scheme-color__palette td');


    schemeColorList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        if(e.target.className === "scheme-color__option") {
            for (var j = 0; j < schemeColorOptions.length; j++) {
                var optionItem = schemeColorOptions[j];
                optionItem.checked = false;
                optionItem.classList.remove('is-selected');
            }
            e.target.classList.add('is-selected');
            e.target.children[0].checked = true;

            var selectedColor = document.querySelector('.scheme-color__option.is-selected').children[2];
            var colors = selectedColor.querySelectorAll('.scheme-color__palette td');
            for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                var pColor = colors[0].style.backgroundColor;
                var sColor = colors[1].style.backgroundColor;
                var tColor = colors[2].style.backgroundColor;
                var qColor = colors[3].style.backgroundColor;
            }

            var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
            for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
                var rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules || styleSheets[i].rules;

                for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {

                     if(rules[j].selectorText === ".site-header") {
                        rules[j].style.backgroundColor = pColor;
                    } else if (rules[j].selectorText === ".site-nav") {
                        rules[j].style.backgroundColor = sColor;
                        rules[j].style.borderColor = tColor;
                    } else if (rules[j].selectorText === ".site-nav__link:hover") {
                        rules[j].style.backgroundColor = pColor;
                    }

                }
            }

        }            
    });
```

The HTML:

```
<section class="section--medium">
            <h3>Choose Color Scheme</h3>

            <div class="scheme-color__list">

                <div class="scheme-color__option is-selected">
                <input type="radio" name="theme-color-input" id="theme-color-default" value="value">
                <label for="theme-color-default">Default Color Scheme</label>
                <table class="scheme-color__palette">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #252527;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #373737;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #232323;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #eee333;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div class="scheme-color__option">
                <input type="radio" name="theme-color-input" id="theme-color-coffee" value="value">
                <label for="theme-color-coffee">Coffee</label>
                <table class="scheme-color__palette">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #46403c">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #59524c">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #c7a589">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #9ea476">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div class="scheme-color__option">
                <input type="radio" name="theme-color-input" id="theme-color-midnight" value="value">
                <label for="theme-color-midnight">Midnight</label>
                <table class="scheme-color__palette">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: #25282b">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #363b3f">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #69a8bb">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #e14d43">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div class="scheme-color__option">
                <input type="radio" name="theme-color-input" id="theme-color-light" value="value">
                <label for="theme-color-light">Professional</label>
                <table class="scheme-color__palette">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #222">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #333">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #0073aa">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="background-color: #00a0d2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div class="scheme-color__option">
                <input type="radio" name="theme-color-input" id="theme-color-sunrise" value="value">
                <label for="theme-color-sunrise">Sunrise</label>
                <table class="scheme-color__palette">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #eee333;"></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #eee333;"></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #eee333;"></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #eee333;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /scheme-color list -->

        </section>
```

Comment: You could walk up the `parentNode` chain to see if the clicked target is under a node with the `scheme-color__option` class.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same but how would you do this for all the elements that are under the scheme-color__option?